# Torrent clients don't seem to be working on 20.04

Tags: bittorrent, transmission, deluge

I've recently updated to 20.04 and everything seems to be running smoothely except none of the torrent clients I try seem to want to work.

When I try using Transmission all that happens after I try to download anythign is it just sits and does nothing. Similar story with qbittorrent.

When I try using deluge I get this happening:
[image]

It's been sat like this for nearly half an hour now and hasn't progressed at all.

Anyone have any ideas as to what's up and how to fix?

Comment: Hmmmm. My torrent client is working properly in 20.04. Have you checked that the application is binding to the correct ports? Have you made any changes to your firewall or router or other networking chages?

Comment: I've not made any changes to the router, firewall, or anything like that.

How would I quickly check if it's binding to the correct ports?

Comment: I find `ss -p` to be very useful for such troubleshooting. You can filter the results using `grep`.

Comment: I'll give it a bash later tonight. what client do oyu usually use?

Comment: After a while of trying I've coem to the conclusion that I don't know enough about what I'm doing to be able to figure this out.

Would anyone be able to like... help me through this slowly? I'm not skilled or knowleedgable enough.

Comment: Please don't comment on your own question. We comment, you [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1246193/edit). Comments are intended to help you improve your question, not for conversation. AskUbuntu's format is Question/Answer, not threaded conversation. Right now, your question is not answerable -- you did not answer the port question, you have not described your network (home? school/corporate?). After that, you will need to revisit your torrent client and Ubuntu firewall and router firewall settings, and likely need to show us those.